# Как расшифровать хеш?

Tags: c++, хеширование

Есть строка зашифрованная(std::hash). Как её можно расшифровать?

Comment: Можно было из описания [метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%85%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/info) понять.

Comment: Наверное вам стоило написать зачем вам это. Если вы точно хотите "расшифровать хэш" то можете поискать словосочетание "радужная таблица"

Answer (score 12):

Никак. Это не *шифрование*, это скорее дайджест. Один и тот же хэш может соответствовать разным исходным значениям, что уже формально не дает возможности однозначного выяснения исходного значения.